# How can I rotate font-awesome icon on hover without spinning texts?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'm practicing html and having problem.
First, my code:

```css
i:hover{
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition: 1s all;
}
i{
  transition: 1s all;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
 <i class="fa fa-car">This is a car.</i>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to make my icon spin when hovering at icon and text, but when I hover with this code, entire text spins. What should I do to make my car spin without spinning the whole line? Do I have to use javascript in this?

Comment: You'd usually not have text inside the Font Awesome 'i' tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rotate the pseudo-element that create the icon:

```css
i:hover::before {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

i:before {
  display: inline-block;/* mandatory to be able to use transform */
  transition: 1s all;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i class="fa fa-car">This is a car.</i>
```